# How do I stop LaTeX from splitting the rows of my nx15 matrices onto more than one line?

Tags: amsmath, matrices, rotating

The rows of all my nx15 matrices have been split onto two lines when I compile my document. This is an example of one, which I've been using the `rotating` package for since it won't fit onto a page unless it's landscape. However it's still splitting it the same as before, and also does this with a 1x15 matrix whose entries should all fit on one line normally without using the `rotating` package.
I've been getting an "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" message. Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,amsmath,rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sideways}
$
\begin{pmatrix}
    0.3754  &  0.1299  &  0.3271  &  0.2008  &  0.1111  &  0.1563  &  0.3446 &  0.1116  &  0.1186  &  0.2424  &  0.1428  &  0.1925  &  0.3882  &  0.1814 &  0.2174 \\
    0.2021  &  0.0812  &  0.1162  &  0.1275  &  0.0556  &  0.0905  &  0.1239 &  0.1081  &  0.3636  &  0.2424  &  0.3497  &  0.1925  &  0.2152  &  0.1026 &  0.1133 \\
    0.0954  &  0.2364  &  0.0812  &  0.3503  &  0.2222  &  0.1563  &  0.1741 &  0.1996  &  0.1186  &  0.0606  &  0.2010  &  0.1925  &  0.1212  &  0.3168 &  0.2174 \\
    0.1327  &  0.0484  &  0.1717  &  0.0931  &  0.1111  &  0.3046  &  0.1741 &  0.3587  &  0.2032  &  0.2424  &  0.1164  &  0.1925  &  0.0987  &  0.0594 &  0.2174 \\
    0.0705  &  0.2364  &  0.1717  &  0.1082  &  0.2222  &  0.1236  &  0.0852 &  0.0596  &  0.0750  &  0.0303  &  0.0774  &  0.0388  &  0.0442  &  0.1026 &  0.0567 \\
    0.0620  &  0.2253  &  0.0507  &  0.0777  &  0.2222  &  0.0782  &  0.0490 &  0.1217  &  0.0581  &  0.1212  &  0.0426  &  0.1518  &  0.0822  &  0.1814 &  0.1133 \\
    0.0620  &  0.0424  &  0.0812  &  0.0424  &  0.0556  &  0.0905  &  0.0490 &  0.0406  &  0.0629  &  0.0606  &  0.0702  &  0.0395  &  0.0503  &  0.0556 &  0.0644 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
\end{sideways}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. By default, the matrix-like environments of the `amsmath` package -- `matrix`, `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, etc -- are not supposed to have more than 10 columns. If your matrix has 15 columns, you should run `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 4):

`tabstackengine` comes with no stinkin' column limits!  HOOAH!

Generally, for straightforward things like matrices, the `amsmath` environments are fully prepared to handle your needs.  Where TABstacks can be useful is when the requirement is slightly different from the default configuration.  With simple mode settings, `tabstackengine` can immediately do things like

1. handle more than 10 columns automaTeXly
2. change the default inter-column gap
3. change the default inter-row baselineskip (long stacks) or inter-row vertical gap (short stacks)
4. change the default matrix mode between text or math
5. make all columns of equal width
6. apply a fixed formatting style to all elements (e.g., `\displaystyle` in math mode or `\footnotesize` in text mode)
7. flexible alignments (in the mode of `array` or `tabular`)
8. with the new V2.10 of the package, cell over/underlining in the mode of `\cline` (called `\TABrule` or `\TABcline{}` in the package)

Also, the package remembers the individual cell contents and dimensions (including the content dimensions, the row height/depth, as well as the column width) of the most recently typeset TABstack (or can be queried with a hypothetical TABstack that is not typeset).  There are various ways in which one could write macros to take advantage of this information, such as overlaying stuff atop the matrix at known cell locations, deciding on the fly whether to break the typesetting of the matrix into several pieces, etc.

Here is the MWE addressing the OP's matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,rotating,tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{sideways}
$
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
\parenMatrixstack{
    0.3754  &  0.1299  &  0.3271  &  0.2008  &  0.1111  &  0.1563  &  0.3446 &  0.1116  &  0.1186  &  0.2424  &  0.1428  &  0.1925  &  0.3882  &  0.1814 &  0.2174 \\
    0.2021  &  0.0812  &  0.1162  &  0.1275  &  0.0556  &  0.0905  &  0.1239 &  0.1081  &  0.3636  &  0.2424  &  0.3497  &  0.1925  &  0.2152  &  0.1026 &  0.1133 \\
    0.0954  &  0.2364  &  0.0812  &  0.3503  &  0.2222  &  0.1563  &  0.1741 &  0.1996  &  0.1186  &  0.0606  &  0.2010  &  0.1925  &  0.1212  &  0.3168 &  0.2174 \\
    0.1327  &  0.0484  &  0.1717  &  0.0931  &  0.1111  &  0.3046  &  0.1741 &  0.3587  &  0.2032  &  0.2424  &  0.1164  &  0.1925  &  0.0987  &  0.0594 &  0.2174 \\
    0.0705  &  0.2364  &  0.1717  &  0.1082  &  0.2222  &  0.1236  &  0.0852 &  0.0596  &  0.0750  &  0.0303  &  0.0774  &  0.0388  &  0.0442  &  0.1026 &  0.0567 \\
    0.0620  &  0.2253  &  0.0507  &  0.0777  &  0.2222  &  0.0782  &  0.0490 &  0.1217  &  0.0581  &  0.1212  &  0.0426  &  0.1518  &  0.0822  &  0.1814 &  0.1133 \\
    0.0620  &  0.0424  &  0.0812  &  0.0424  &  0.0556  &  0.0905  &  0.0490 &  0.0406  &  0.0629  &  0.0606  &  0.0702  &  0.0395  &  0.0503  &  0.0556 &  0.0644 
}
$
\end{sideways}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for those of us who aren't fully familiar with `\parenMatrixstack`, would you maybe add a sentence or two to mention what this macro can, and cannot, do? E.g., what are its pluses relative to the `amsmath` package's `pmatrix` environment -- other than the fact that there's no default maximum number of columns?

Answer (score 1):

You  can use the `medsize`command from `nccmath`(~80 % of \displaystyle) to make the matrix fit the text height. As the matrix parenthese are a litlle tight for my taste, I added some vertical spacing at the top and bottom of the matrix with the `\Gape` command from `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[showframe]{article}
\usepackage{geometry, mathtools, nccmath, rotating, makecell}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
    \begin{sideways}
    $ \begin{medsize}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0.3754 & 0.1299 & 0.3271 & 0.2008 & 0.1111 & 0.1563 & 0.3446 & 0.1116 & 0.1186 & 0.2424 & 0.1428 & 0.1925 & 0.3882 & 0.1814 & \Gape[1.5ex][0pt]{0.2174}\\
    0.2021 & 0.0812 & 0.1162 & 0.1275 & 0.0556 & 0.0905 & 0.1239 & 0.1081 & 0.3636 & 0.2424 & 0.3497 & 0.1925 & 0.2152 & 0.1026 & 0.1133 \\
    0.0954 & 0.2364 & 0.0812 & 0.3503 & 0.2222 & 0.1563 & 0.1741 & 0.1996 & 0.1186 & 0.0606 & 0.2010 & 0.1925 & 0.1212 & 0.3168 & 0.2174 \\
    0.1327 & 0.0484 & 0.1717 & 0.0931 & 0.1111 & 0.3046 & 0.1741 & 0.3587 & 0.2032 & 0.2424 & 0.1164 & 0.1925 & 0.0987 & 0.0594 & 0.2174 \\
    0.0705 & 0.2364 & 0.1717 & 0.1082 & 0.2222 & 0.1236 & 0.0852 & 0.0596 & 0.0750 & 0.0303 & 0.0774 & 0.0388 & 0.0442 & 0.1026 & 0.0567 \\
    0.0620 & 0.2253 & 0.0507 & 0.0777 & 0.2222 & 0.0782 & 0.0490 & 0.1217 & 0.0581 & 0.1212 & 0.0426 & 0.1518 & 0.0822 & 0.1814 & 0.1133 \\
    0.0620 & 0.0424 & 0.0812 & 0.0424 & 0.0556 & 0.0905 & 0.0490 & 0.0406 & 0.0629 & 0.0606 & 0.0702 & 0.0395 & 0.0503 & 0.0556 & \Gape[0pt][1.5ex]{0.0644} \\
    \end{pmatrix}\hskip 4.5em
    \end{medsize} $
    \end{sideways}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]